# Rails, update a database record after something has been rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there way to update a record after something has been rendered without putting the code in my view?

For example I'm displaying messages to my users, and after the messages have been displayed I want to update the `read` attribute to `true`. What would be the best practice for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails 2.3 you can do a `after_filter` in much the same way you would do a `before_filter`. So, for example:

```
class MyController << ApplicationController
  after_filter :mark_read

  def mark_read
    @message.update_attribute(:read, true)
  end
end
```